# Finding the value of $(\log_x y)^2 + (\log_y x)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The problem goes like this:

> Let $x$ and $y$ be two positive real numbers such that $$\log_x y + \log_y x = 3.$$ Find the value of$$(\log_x y)^2 + (\log_y x)^2.$$

So, I simplified the problem to look like this:$$ 2\log_x y + 2\log_y x.$$ And then following that, I factored out the two, leaving me with this:$$ 2(\log_x y + \log_y x). $$

From there, I am stuck because I do not know how to integrate the $3$ from the original equation into this new one, as I am sure the value of this new one has something to do with the $3$ given in the problem. Is the $3$ squared or is the $3$ left as is, or am I forgetting to do something else not mentioned...?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\log_x(y^2)+\log_y(x^2)$?

Comment: Assuming so, just substitute $\log_x y+\log_y x=3$ into the expression you derived.

Comment: If I tell you that $a+b=3$, can you work out the value of $2(a+b)$?

Comment: Yes. I edited the formatting. I am a little new here so it took me a while to understand how to format it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

- If the problem is about finding $\log_x (y^2)+\log_y(x^2)$... $\log_x (y^2)+\log_y(x^2)=2\log_x y+2\log_y x=2(\log_x y+\log_y x)=2\cdot 3 = 6$.
- If the problem is about finding $(\log_x y)^2+(\log_y x)^2$: note $(\log_x y)^2+(\log_y x)^2=(\log_x y)^2+2+(\log_y x)^2-2=(\log_x y)^2+2\log_x y\log_y x+(\log_y x)^2-2=(\log_x y+\log_y x)^2-2=3^2-2=7$.

We have used that $\log_x y\cdot \log_y x=1$.